# Print multidimensional array individually getting from an api in php

Tags: php, arrays

i want to print this individually. How to convert it in array so that i can print this value

```
[
    {"id":19,"name":"The Rainbow Room","desc":"Guppy X Delta Network Party","category":"Party","photos":
        [{"id":21,"url":"http:\/\/delta.development.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/system\/App\/Models\/EventPhoto\/photos\/000\/000\/021\/medium\/Rainbow%20328x%20716-02%20%282%29.png"}]
    },{"id":22,"name":"Kashish 2018 ","desc":"Together with Pride","category":"Film Festival","photos":[]
    },{"id":21,"name":"Cosplay Night","desc":"Guppy X Delta Network Party","category":"Party","photos":
    [{"id":20,"url":"http:\/\/delta.development.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com\/system\/App\/Models\/EventPhoto\/photos\/000\/000\/020\/medium\/Cosplay%20328x%20716-01%20%282%29.png"}]
    }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried to so far to accomplish your goal? Did you take a look into the php documentation, like `foreach` loops?

Answer (score 0):

json_decode will convert json to object or array

`json_decode($json, true);`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

In order to print each individual item you need to convert your three dimensional array into two dimensional array:

```
$mainarray = json_decode($jsondata, true);
$formatted =[];
foreach($mainarray as $key=>$value){
    if(is_array($value)){
        foreach($value as $k=>$v){          
            if(is_array($v)){
                foreach($v as $sk=>$sv){
                    $formatted[$key]['photoid'] = $sv['id'];
                    $formatted[$key]['photourl'] = $sv['url'];
                }
            }else{
                $formatted[$key][$k] = $v;
            }

        }
    }
}
print_r($formatted);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 19
            [name] => The Rainbow Room
            [desc] => Guppy X Delta Network Party
            [category] => Party
            [photoid] => 21
            [photourl] => http://delta.development.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/system/App/Models/EventPhoto/photos/000/000/021/medium/Rainbow%20328x%20716-02%20%282%29.png
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 22
            [name] => Kashish 2018 
            [desc] => Together with Pride
            [category] => Film Festival
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 21
            [name] => Cosplay Night
            [desc] => Guppy X Delta Network Party
            [category] => Party
            [photoid] => 20
            [photourl] => http://delta.development.s3.ap-southeast-1.amazonaws.com/system/App/Models/EventPhoto/photos/000/000/020/medium/Cosplay%20328x%20716-01%20%282%29.png
        )

)
```

To print the data:

```
foreach($formatted as $data=>$row){
    echo $row['name']."\n";
}
```

Output:

```
The Rainbow Room
Kashish 2018 
Cosplay Night
```

To print the first name:

```
echo $formatted[0]['name'];//for second change zero(0) to [1]
```